# Eclipse oxygen crashes on startup while converting a project to java 11

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-oxygen

I have a project which uses java 1.7, which I need to convert in Java 11.
I installed Eclipse oxygen.3 and changes the .ini file like this:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.551.v20171108-1834
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-showsplash
org.eclipse.epp.package.common
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.9\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11.0.9
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11.0.9
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
```

in .metadata logs I am getting org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
But still on launching the eclipse it is crashing, without giving any error. Please someone help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: Eclipse Oxygen is too old to run with anything after Java 8. Either move to the current Eclipse 2020-12 or go back to Java 8.